# FFMPEG - Save Snapshot every n seconds from local stream

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, video-streaming

I have a pi4 running, OctoPrint 1.7.2, Python 3.7.3, OctoPi 0.18.0
with a usb camera attached (Logitech c922 pro). The feed is viewable from `http://[ip address]/webcam/?action=snapshot` and `http://[ip address]/webcam/?action=stream`

I'm not sure exactly how octoprint is streaming the feed. I 'think' they are using mjpg-streamer. with the service named webcamd

I need to save an image every n seconds for a set amount of time  (save an image every 5 seconds, for 3 hours). Should I write some python code to use the 'snapshot' url?   or is there a better way to do this with just FFMPEG?

Comment: You have `ffmpeg` running... please show **how**. Thank you.

Comment: show how?   I have octoprint (octopi) installed on the Pi, so that automatically has FFMPEG installed.  I'm trying to manually trigger a time lapse on it.

Comment: You said `ffmpeg` is running. I wanted to know exactly what command you are running and how it is launched. You could also identify your camera make and model and your OS. Thank you.

Comment: ok,  ffmpeg is installed, but they are using  mjpg-streamer for the stream.  I edited my original post with more details

Answer (score -1):

[This script](https://github.com/chriscohoat/octoprint-scripts/tree/master/src/manual_timelapse/) seems to do what I need it to:

main.py:

```py
import requests
import os
import datetime
import time

def start_taking_snapshots(output_directory):
    if os.path.exists(output_directory):
        raise Exception("Output directory already exists.")
    os.makedirs(output_directory)
    snapshot_url = "PUBLIC_OCTOPRINT_URL/webcam/?action=snapshot"
    image_number = 0

    while True:
        output_filename = os.path.join(output_directory, "%s.jpg" % image_number)
        r = requests.get(snapshot_url, stream=True)
        r.raise_for_status()
        with open(output_filename, "wb") as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                if chunk:
                    f.write(chunk)
                    f.flush()
        image_number += 1
        time.sleep(2)

def main():
    start_taking_snapshots(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```